# R - difference devtools::load_all vs loading functions manually

Tags: r, validation, devtools

I am creating a package which uses the validate package. I want to run this function:

```
validate_run <- function() {
  rules <- validator( speed >= 0,
                      dist >= 0)

  out <- confront(cars, rules)

  print("hello")
  print(summary(out))

  }
```

The expected output would be:

```
[1] "hello"
  name items passes fails nNA error warning          expression
1   V1    50     50     0   0 FALSE   FALSE speed - 0 >= -1e-08
2   V2    50     50     0   0 FALSE   FALSE  dist - 0 >= -1e-08
```

This is also the output of calling the function if I load the function into memory using `source` or I load it in an active R session.

However if I load in this function using `devtools::load_all` the output of calling the function becomes:

```
[1] "hello"
    Length      Class       Mode 
         2 validation         S4
```

Why is this difference? How should I write my functions for this output to be the same?

**edit:**
To be clear, I am creating a new package with it's own DESCRIPTION. I want to load all the functions of this new package by just running `devtools::load_all()` to load all the functions defined in the R folder of this new package.

Answer (score 0):

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/data-cleaning/validate/issues/169) on the validate github repo and there my question got answered. The answers are very thorough so I would advice people to read them.

In short the reason for the difference was that loading the function in an active R session or using `source`, makes it so that the `summary` function exported by the validate package is used. When loading the function using `devtools::load_all` a generic `summary`function for S4 objects is used. Using full imports(`validate::summary`) solved the issue. This is actually also a best practise when doing package development in R.